# How can I check if a URL exists with Django’s validators?

Tags: django, url, url-validation

I want to check in django if a URL exists and if it does I want to show something on screen, i.e.:

```
if URL_THAT_POINTS_TO_SOME_PDF exists 
     SHOW_SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Edit: Please note, this is no longer valid for any version of Django above 1.5**

I assume you want to check if the file actually exists, not if there is just an object (which is just a simple if statement)

First, I will recommend always looking through Django's source code because you will [find some great code](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/validators.py#L41) that you could use :)

I assume you want to do this within a template. There is no built-in template tag to validate a URL but you could essentially use that `URLValidator` class within a template tag to test it. Simply:

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

validate = URLValidator(verify_exists=True)
try:
    validate('http://www.somelink.com/to/my.pdf')
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

The `URLValidator` class will spit out the `ValidationError` when it can't open the link. It uses `urllib2` to actually open the request so it's not just using basic regex checking (But it also does that.)

You can plop this into a custom template tag, which you will find out how to create in the django docs and off you go.

Hope that is a start for you.

Comment: `verify_exists` is [deprecated for security](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.URLField.verify_exists) reasons and has been removed in Django 1.5

Comment: since django 1.5, verify_exists argument has been deprecated/removed, you can no longer verify for a url existence, its now just a simple regex match for a valid url

Comment: [depricated warning link in internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907152504/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.URLField.verify_exists)

Answer (score 11):

**Problem**

`from django.core.validators import URLValidator` says that `www.google.ro` is invalid. Which is wrong in my point of view. Or at least not enough.

**How to solve it?**

The clue Is to look at the source code for `models.URLField`, you will see that it uses `forms.FormField` as a validator. Which does more than `URLValidator` from above

**Solution**

If I want to validate a `url` like `http://www.google.com` or like `www.google.ro`, I would do the following:

from django.forms import URLField

```
def validate_url(url):
    url_form_field = URLField()
    try:
        url = url_form_field.clean(url)
    except ValidationError:
        return False
    return True
```

I found this useful. Maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score 6):

Anything based on the `verify_exists` parameter to `django.core.validators.URLValidator` will stop working with Django 1.5 — [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/validators/#urlvalidator) helpfully says nothing about this, but the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/validators.py#L80) reveals that using that mechanism in 1.4 (the latest stable version) leads to a `DeprecationWarning` (you'll see [it has been removed completely in the development version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py)):

```
if self.verify_exists:
    import warnings
    warnings.warn(
        "The URLField verify_exists argument has intractable security "
        "and performance issues. Accordingly, it has been deprecated.",
        DeprecationWarning
        )
```

There are also some odd quirks with this method related to the fact that it uses a `HEAD` request to check URLs — bandwidth-efficient, sure, but some sites (like Amazon) respond with an error (to `HEAD`, where the equivalent `GET` would have been fine), and this leads to [false negative results from the validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940288/django-urlvalidator-produced-bogus-errors/11940521#11940521).

I would also (a lot has changed in two years) recommend against doing anything with `urllib2` in a template — this is completely the wrong part of the request/response cycle to be triggering potentially long-running operations: consider what happens if the URL does exist, but a DNS problem causes `urllib2` to take 10 seconds to work that out. BAM! Instant 10 extra seconds on your page load.

I would say the current best practice for making possibly-long-running tasks like this asynchronous (and thus not blocking page load) is using `django-celery`; there's [a basic tutorial](http://query7.com/tutorial-celery-with-django) which covers using `pycurl` to check a website, or you could look into [how Simon Willison implemented celery tasks](http://www.slideshare.net/simon/building-lanyrd) (slides 32-41) for a similar purpose on Lanyrd.

Answer (score 2):

It took an additional:

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

for it to work for me. Just saying ;0)

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

validate = URLValidator(verify_exists=True)    
value = request.GET.get('url', None)

if value:        
    try:
        validate(value)
    except ValidationError, e:
        print e
```

`validate(value)` fails if the url is not preceeded with a schema like `http://`. I wonder if that is by design.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen the answer here. It might helpful to someone else.

```
from django import forms
f = forms.URLField()
try:
    f.clean(http://example.com)
    print "valid url"
except:
    print "invalid url"
```

Comment: I was going to put a similar asnwer. You had a good try, but it is not enough.

Comment: @MihaiZamfir: why is this not enough?

Answer (score 0):

See:
http://www.agmweb.ca/2009-04-19-django-urlpatterns---its-more-than-just-urls/

In django 1.10 i now use:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import RegexURLResolver, Resolver404

if 'next' in request.GET.keys():
    n = request.GET["next"].strip('/') + "/"
    resolver = RegexURLResolver(r'', urls)
    try:
        callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = resolver.resolve(n)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(str(request.GET["next"]))
    except Resolver404:
        raise PermissionDenied("This page is not available")
```

Answer (score 0):

For new version of Django, you should just when a non valid url is given it raises a Validation exception **django.core.exceptionValidationError**

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator                                                                                                                             
validate = URLValidator()                                                                                                                                                                  
validate('http://www.google.com')                                                                                                                                                                
validate('http://www2.google.com')                                                                                                                                                               
validate('httpAA://www2.google.com')                                                                                                                                                             
     Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                     
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                
     File "/etl/.venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
     packages/django/core/validators.py", line 110, in __call__                                                                                                         
     raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code, params={'value': value})                                                                                                                     
     django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Enter a valid URL.']
```