# How to validate a url in Python? (Malformed or not)

Tags: python, url, malformedurlexception

I have `url` from the user and I have to reply with the fetched HTML.

How can I check for the URL to be malformed or not?

For example :

```
url = 'google' # Malformed
url = 'google.com' # Malformed
url = 'http://google.com' # Valid
url = 'http://google' # Malformed
```

Comment: Just try to read it, if for instance httplib throws an exception, then you'll know it was invalid. _Not all well formed urls are valid_!

Comment: `url='http://google' ` is not malformed. Schema + hostname is always valid.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

## django url validation regex ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/core/validators.py#L45)):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
        r'localhost|' #localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
        r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)

print(re.match(regex, "http://www.example.com") is not None) # True
print(re.match(regex, "example.com") is not None)            # False
```

Comment: a curiosity... did you add the `ftp`? Or have I an old django version?

Comment: >>wiso: django version 1.3 ( make sure yourself: /django/core/validators.py, line:47 )  ftp://someftp.com - invalid url ? Even stackoferlow parser someftp.com makes as link )

Comment: >>Yugal Jindle: django developers thinks protocol is required, but you can modify this regexp if you do not think so

Comment: Sorry, I meant url='http://www.google' is malformed right ?
But it matches the regex.. so can something be done for that ?

Comment: @yugal-jindle http://www.sitedomain is not a valid url. http://www.museum/ is because .museum is a top-level-domain (ICANN [1] defines them), and not a sitedomain. [1] http://www.icann.org/

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work with http://username:password@example.com style URLs

Comment: does anybody have a link to the source in its context?

Comment: @cowlinator https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.3.x/django/core/validators.py#L45

Comment: I found a bug: `httpbin.org`

Comment: This will not work for IPv6 urls, which have the form `http://[2001:0DB8::3]:8080/index.php?valid=true#result`

Comment: url='http://google' is actually a valid url in most browsers. It is common to use on internal networks to allow the use of http://myserver/mypage instead of http://myserver.myoffice.mydomain.com for obvious reasons. Most people will want to allow the local short server name.

Comment: Can you explain how this regular expression works? `r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...`

Answer (score 233):

Use the [validators](http://validators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package:

```
>>> import validators
>>> validators.url("http://google.com")
True
>>> validators.url("http://google")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://google', 'require_tld': True})
>>> if not validators.url("http://google"):
...     print "not valid"
... 
not valid
>>>
```

Install it [from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/validators/) with pip (`pip install validators`).

Comment: It will throw error for file urls. Like "file:///users/file.txt"

Comment: Fails for localhost urls

 
```validators.url("http://localhost:8080")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'public': False, 'value': 'http://localhost:8080'})

```

Comment: valid for `http://www.google`, `http://google.www`.. this is simply checking for `http://` and `a dot (.) between two words`

Comment: The package's validating fn has many arbitrary limitations, so it's a terrible advice to suggest it as a general solution.

Comment: In [4]: validators.url("http://google.fndwjbveiuw")
Out[4]: True

Comment: Update: the previous errors are fixed in the latest version.

Comment: @Fanglin no, the errors are not fixed. `validators.url("file:///some_file.txt")` gives a failure.

Comment: This does not consider perfectly valid URLs as valid. Like single word hostnames on a corporate network."

Comment: This package is not maintained actively

Comment: @MehdiZare, there are commits from yesterday... so I'd say it is at least to some extent maintained.

Comment: As of Jan 16 2024 this package no longer uses the argument `public` and the maintainer has not mentioned any commitment to bring it back, despite it being described in the documented source code. Id suggest migrating away from this package.

Answer (score 154):

Actually, I think this is the best way.

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

val = URLValidator(verify_exists=False)
try:
    val('http://www.google.com')
except ValidationError, e:
    print e
```

If you set `verify_exists` to `True`, it will actually verify that the URL exists, otherwise it will just check if it's formed correctly.

edit: ah yeah, this question is a duplicate of this: [How can I check if a URL exists with Django’s validators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170231/django-url-validation-i-just-want-to-see-if-the-url-exists)

Comment: But this will only work in the django environment not otherwise.

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know why I thought this question had the django tag. Yikes, sorry.

Comment: `verify_exists` is deprecated. -1

Comment: Add: from django.conf import settings
settings.configure(DEBUG=False) and remove the verify_exists to keep it working with django 1.5

Comment: @YugalJindle Correct, but stripping it from Django is almost trivial :D. So, I use this method

Comment: Note, with django >= 1.5 there is no `verify_exists` anymore. Also instead of the `val` variable you can call it like `URLValidator()('http://www.google.com')`

Comment: Would it make sense to import Django just to do a URL validation?

Comment: What does the val function return though?  That needs to be specified here.  I tested it out, and the val function returns None if the argument is a url and throws a validation error otherwise.

Answer (score 150):

A True or False version, based on @DMfll answer:

```
try:
    # python2
    from urlparse import urlparse
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # python3
    from urllib.parse import urlparse

a = 'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
b = '/data/Python.html'
c = 532
d = u'dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk'
e = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

def uri_validator(x):
    try:
        result = urlparse(x)
        return all([result.scheme, result.netloc])
    except AttributeError:
        return False

print(uri_validator(a))
print(uri_validator(b))
print(uri_validator(c))
print(uri_validator(d))
print(uri_validator(e))
```

Gives:

```
True
False
False
False
True
```

Comment: I didn't know you could test an if statement with a list of non-None elements. That's helpful. Also +1 for using a built-in module

Comment: Empty lists maps to False in condition contexts.

Comment: This allows everything.  It returns `True` for the string `fake` or even for a blank string.  There will never be any errors because those attributes are always there, and the list will always have a boolean value of True because it contains those attributes.  Even if all of the attributes are None, the list will still be non-empty.  You need some validation of the attributes because everything passes the way you have it now.

Comment: Lists of false objects evaluate to True: `print("I am true") if [False, None, 0, '', [], {}] else print("I am false.")` prints "I am true." when I run it. `[result.scheme, result.netloc, result.path]` always evaluates to `True`. `print("I am True") if [] else print("I am False.")` prints "I am false." so empty lists are False. The contents of the array needs evaluation with something like the `all` function.

Comment: I've edited it to `return result.scheme and result.netloc and result.path` instead of doing a comparison with a non-empty list (which is always `True` as noted by others above.)

Comment: Not sure why you would require a path like that. You should remove `result.path` from the test.

Comment: This is good enough for me, thanks. I just added a simple validation for `scheme`:

`if not all([result.scheme in ["file", "http", "https"], result.netloc, result.path]):`

Comment: @AlexanderFortin, right, the `scheme` is allowed to be a whatever string here, so this check is needed. For example blocking `javascript:` could prevent XSS attacks. The best method here is to whitelist few allowed schemes, as you have done in your comment.

Comment: Rotten algorithm. This validates malformed URIs, like `https://https://https://www.foo.bar` as `ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='https:', path='//https://www.foo.bar', params='', query='', fragment='')`. **IN OTHER WORDS IT PASSES MANGLED URIs.**

Comment: @alemol Can you specify what type of error is in except? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: This returns false for a file URL: `file:///home/user`

Comment: For those who likes on-liners: `is_valid = all(list(urllib.parse.urlparse(url))[:2])`

Comment: +1 for maybe being a bit more careful with such examples ... you should really think twice before encouraging others to use 'catch-all' exception handlers with an SO reply. Not sure what a good reference for this is, but surely you're risking hiding errors that are misinterpreted. Perhaps investigate at least what classes to watch out for?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding

(See jonaprieto's answer with ValueError for a possible resolution - I myself haven't verified that.)

Comment: This returns false for urls without a path - e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I've updated the example to not require a path, as that's not required

Answer (score 38):

Nowadays, I use the following, based on the Padam's answer:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
```

And this is how it looks:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_url(url):
  try:
    result = urlparse(url)
    return all([result.scheme, result.netloc])
  except ValueError:
    return False
```

Just use `is_url("http://www.asdf.com")`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It fails in case the domain name begins with a dash, which is not valid. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952

Comment: This is only good to split up components in the special case that the URI is known to **NOT** be malformed. As I replied earlier to the other similar answer, this validates malformed URIs, like `https://https://https://www.foo.bar`.

Comment: As of Python 3.7.6, I tested this logic with "https://-wee.com" and it worked

Answer (score 21):

I landed on this page trying to figure out a sane way to validate strings as "valid" urls. I share here my solution using python3. No extra libraries required.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html if you are using python2.

See https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html if you are using python3 as I am.

```
import urllib
from pprint import pprint

invalid_url = 'dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk'
valid_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
tokens = [urllib.parse.urlparse(url) for url in (invalid_url, valid_url)]

for token in tokens:
    pprint(token)
    
min_attributes = ('scheme', 'netloc')  # add attrs to your liking
for token in tokens:
    if all(getattr(token, attr) for attr in min_attributes) is False:
        error = "'{url}' string has no scheme or netloc.".format(url=token.geturl())
        print(error)
    else:
        print("'{url}' is probably a valid url.".format(url=token.geturl()))
```

> ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk', params='', query='', fragment='')

> ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')

> 'dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk' string has no scheme or netloc.

> 'https://stackoverflow.com' is probably a valid url.

Here is a more concise function:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

min_attributes = ('scheme', 'netloc')


def is_valid(url, qualifying=min_attributes):
    tokens = urlparse(url)
    return all(getattr(tokens, qualifying_attr)
               for qualifying_attr in qualifying)
```

Here is a useage example. I prefer to do any exception handling outside of a function.

```
my_list = [
    "http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html",
    "/data/Python.html",
    532,
    type("FooObject", (), {"decode": None})(),
    "dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk",
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
]

for item in my_list:
    try:
        print(f"{item} is valid: {is_valid(item)}")
    except (AttributeError, TypeError) as e:
        print(e)
```

OUTPUT:

> http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html is valid: True

> /data/Python.html is valid: False

> 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

> dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk is valid: False

> https://stackoverflow.com is valid: True

Comment: Best answer on here from the custom-coded solutions.

Answer (score 10):

**note** - lepl is no longer supported, sorry (you're welcome to use it, and i think the code below works, but it's not going to get updates).

rfc 3696 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3696.html defines how to do this (for http urls and email).  i implemented its recommendations in python using lepl (a parser library).  see http://acooke.org/lepl/rfc3696.html

to use:

```
> easy_install lepl
...
> python
...
>>> from lepl.apps.rfc3696 import HttpUrl
>>> validator = HttpUrl()
>>> validator('google')
False
>>> validator('http://google')
False
>>> validator('http://google.com')
True
```

Comment: Neat, but what about FTP, or HTTPS?

Comment: you haven't forked the code and implemented them?  it's open source.

Comment: lepl is now discontinued by the author http://www.acooke.org/lepl/discontinued.html EDIT: heh, just realized that you *are* the author

Comment: note: lepl.apps.rfc3696 is not working in Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**

> As pointed out by @Kwame , the below code does validate the url even if the `.com` or `.co` etc are not present.
>
> also pointed out by @Blaise, URLs like https://www.google is a valid URL 
>   and you need to do a DNS check for checking if it resolves or not, separately.

This is simple and works:

So `min_attr` contains the basic set of strings that needs to be present to define the validity of a URL,
i.e `http://` part and `google.com` part.

`urlparse.scheme` stores `http://` and

`urlparse.netloc` store the domain name `google.com`

```
from urlparse import urlparse
def url_check(url):

    min_attr = ('scheme' , 'netloc')
    try:
        result = urlparse(url)
        if all([result.scheme, result.netloc]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

`all()` returns true if all the variables inside it return true.
So if `result.scheme` and `result.netloc` is present i.e. has some value then the URL is valid and hence returns `True`.

Comment: Oh , Nice catch .. I guess I have to take my code back.
What do you prefer , are there any other options except regex.

Comment: `https://www.google` is a valid URL. It may not actually resolve, but if you care about that you need to do a DNS check.

Comment: swallows exceptions

Answer (score 5):

Here's a regex solution since top voted regex doesn't work for weird cases like top-level domain. Some test cases down below.

```
regex = re.compile(
    r"(\w+://)?"                # protocol                      (optional)
    r"(\w+\.)?"                 # host                          (optional)
    r"(([\w-]+)\.(\w+))"        # domain
    r"(\.\w+)*"                 # top-level domain              (optional, can have > 1)
    r"([\w\-\._\~/]*)*(?<!\.)"  # path, params, anchors, etc.   (optional)
)
```

```
cases = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "http://google.com",
    "https://google.com",
    "www.google.com",
    "google.com",
    "http://www.google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "https://www.google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "http://google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "https://google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "www.google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "google.com/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    # .co.uk top level
    "http://www.google.co.uk",
    "https://www.google.co.uk",
    "http://google.co.uk",
    "https://google.co.uk",
    "www.google.co.uk",
    "google.co.uk",
    "http://www.google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "https://www.google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "http://google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "https://google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "www.google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "google.co.uk/~as_db3.2123/134-1a",
    "https://...",
    "https://..",
    "https://.",
    "https://.google.com",
    "https://..google.com",
    "https://...google.com",
    "https://.google..com",
    "https://.google...com",
    "https://...google..com",
    "https://...google...com",
    ".google.com",
    ".google.co.",
    "https://google.co."
]
for c in cases:
    if regex.match(c):
        print(c, regex.match(c).span()[1] - regex.match(c).span()[0] == len(c))
    else:
        print(c, False)
```

*Edit: Added hyphen to domain as suggested by nickh.*

Comment: error in last line fixed: `print(c, x.span()[1] - x.span()[0] == len(c) if (x := regex.match(c)) else False)`

Comment: Thanks Miguel, but I would like to warn others who do not use Python 3.8+ since ":=" is not valid for former versions.

Comment: It doesn't match domains with hyphens, e.g https://api-example.com
Consider using (\w+://)?(\w+\.)?(([\w-]+)\.(\w+))(\.\w+)*([\w\-\._\~/]*)*(?<!\.)

Comment: it also doesn't match a single word, for example `"fred"`. it gives the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'`

Comment: @colin0117, this shouldn't match a single word. I recommend checking for that edge case in your code.

Comment: @Táwros that's a problem though, it's not an edge case - it's an invalid URL - so the regex solution should reject it.

Comment: No. You should have a function like this

```python
def is_valid_url(string: str) -> bool:
    return regex.match(string) is not None
```

The `re.Pattern.match` method returning None is the indicator that the string is not a valid URL. The for loop in my answer only works with valid URLs. Stick an invalid URL in the cases and it should fail.

Answer (score 3):

## Validate URL with `urllib` and Django-like regex

The Django URL validation regex was actually pretty good but I needed to tweak it a little bit for my use case. **Feel free to adapt it to yours!**

### Python 3.7

```
import re
import urllib

# Check https://regex101.com/r/A326u1/5 for reference
DOMAIN_FORMAT = re.compile(
    r"(?:^(\w{1,255}):(.{1,255})@|^)" # http basic authentication [optional]
    r"(?:(?:(?=\S{0,253}(?:$|:))" # check full domain length to be less than or equal to 253 (starting after http basic auth, stopping before port)
    r"((?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+" # check for at least one subdomain (maximum length per subdomain: 63 characters), dashes in between allowed
    r"(?:[a-z0-9]{1,63})))" # check for top level domain, no dashes allowed
    r"|localhost)" # accept also "localhost" only
    r"(:\d{1,5})?", # port [optional]
    re.IGNORECASE
)
SCHEME_FORMAT = re.compile(
    r"^(http|hxxp|ftp|fxp)s?$", # scheme: http(s) or ftp(s)
    re.IGNORECASE
)

def validate_url(url: str):
    url = url.strip()

    if not url:
        raise Exception("No URL specified")

    if len(url) > 2048:
        raise Exception("URL exceeds its maximum length of 2048 characters (given length={})".format(len(url)))

    result = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    scheme = result.scheme
    domain = result.netloc

    if not scheme:
        raise Exception("No URL scheme specified")

    if not re.fullmatch(SCHEME_FORMAT, scheme):
        raise Exception("URL scheme must either be http(s) or ftp(s) (given scheme={})".format(scheme))

    if not domain:
        raise Exception("No URL domain specified")

    if not re.fullmatch(DOMAIN_FORMAT, domain):
        raise Exception("URL domain malformed (domain={})".format(domain))

    return url
```

### Explanation

- The code only validates the `scheme` and `netloc` part of a given URL. (To do this properly, I split the URL with `urllib.parse.urlparse()` in the two according parts which are then matched with the corresponding regex terms.)
- The `netloc` part stops before the first occurrence of a slash `/`, so `port` numbers are still part of the `netloc`, e.g.:

  ```
  https://www.google.com:80/search?q=python
  ^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |             |      
    |             +-- netloc (aka "domain" in my code)
    +-- scheme
  ```
- IPv4 addresses are also validated

### IPv6 Support

If you want the URL validator to also work with IPv6 addresses, do the following:

- Add `is_valid_ipv6(ip)` from [Markus Jarderot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319293/3459910), which has a really good IPv6 validator regex
- Add `and not is_valid_ipv6(domain)` to the last `if`

### Examples

Here are some examples of the regex for the `netloc` (aka `domain`) part in action:

- **IPv4 and alphanumeric:** https://regex101.com/r/A326u1/5
- **IPv6:** https://regex101.com/r/lKIIgq/1 (with the regex from [Markus Jarderot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319293/3459910))

Answer (score 3):

Pydantic could be used to do that. I'm not very used to it so I can't say about it's limitations. It is an option thou and no one suggested it.

I have seen that many people questioned about ftp and files URL in previous answers so I recommend to get known to the documentation as Pydantic have many types for validation as FileUrl, AnyUrl and even database url types.

A simplistic usage example:

```
from requests import get, HTTPError, ConnectionError
from pydantic import BaseModel, AnyHttpUrl, ValidationError
    
class MyConfModel(BaseModel):
    URI: AnyHttpUrl

try:
    myAddress = MyConfModel(URI = "http://myurl.com/")
    req = get(myAddress.URI, verify=False)
    print(myAddress.URI)

except(ValidationError):
    print('Invalid destination')
```

Pydantic also raises exceptions (pydantic.ValidationError) that can be used to handle errors.

I have teste it with these patterns:

- http://localhost (pass)
- http://localhost:8080 (pass)
- http://example.com (pass)
- http://user:password@example.com (pass)
- http://_example.com (pass)
- http://&example.com (fails)
- http://-example.com (fails)

Answer (score 1):

All of the above solutions recognize a string like "http://www.google.com/path,www.yahoo.com/path" as valid. This solution always works as it should

```
import re

# URL-link validation
ip_middle_octet = u"(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))"
ip_last_octet = u"(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))"

URL_PATTERN = re.compile(
                        u"^"
                        # protocol identifier
                        u"(?:(?:https?|ftp|rtsp|rtp|mmp)://)"
                        # user:pass authentication
                        u"(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?"
                        u"(?:"
                        u"(?P<private_ip>"
                        # IP address exclusion
                        # private & local networks
                        u"(?:localhost)|"
                        u"(?:(?:10|127)" + ip_middle_octet + u"{2}" + ip_last_octet + u")|"
                        u"(?:(?:169\.254|192\.168)" + ip_middle_octet + ip_last_octet + u")|"
                        u"(?:172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])" + ip_middle_octet + ip_last_octet + u"))"
                        u"|"
                        # IP address dotted notation octets
                        # excludes loopback network 0.0.0.0
                        # excludes reserved space >= 224.0.0.0
                        # excludes network & broadcast addresses
                        # (first & last IP address of each class)
                        u"(?P<public_ip>"
                        u"(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])"
                        u"" + ip_middle_octet + u"{2}"
                        u"" + ip_last_octet + u")"
                        u"|"
                        # host name
                        u"(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9_-]-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9_-]+)"
                        # domain name
                        u"(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9_-]-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9_-]+)*"
                        # TLD identifier
                        u"(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))"
                        u")"
                        # port number
                        u"(?::\d{2,5})?"
                        # resource path
                        u"(?:/\S*)?"
                        # query string
                        u"(?:\?\S*)?"
                        u"$",
                        re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE
                       )
def url_validate(url):   
    """ URL string validation
    """                                                                                                                                                      
    return re.compile(URL_PATTERN).match(url)
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/path,www.yahoo.com/path *is* valid. See [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986): a `path` is made of `segment`s which are built from `pchar`s which may be `sub-delims` one of which is `","`.

Comment: Yes, the symbol "," is included in the list of acceptable sub-delims, but the line from my example, even in a terrible dream, cannot be a valid url =)

Comment: @СергейДорофий why not? If it is valid according to the grammar for an URI it is valid URI by definition, not sure I follow why you say it can't be valid if it contains valid characters.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly relevant, but often it's required to identify whether some token CAN be a url or not, not necessarily 100% correctly formed (ie, https part omitted and so on). I've read this post and did not find the solution, so I am posting my own here for the sake of completeness.

```
def get_domain_suffixes():
    import requests
    res=requests.get('https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat')
    lst=set()
    for line in res.text.split('\n'):
        if not line.startswith('//'):
            domains=line.split('.')
            cand=domains[-1]
            if cand:
                lst.add('.'+cand)
    return tuple(sorted(lst))

domain_suffixes=get_domain_suffixes()

def reminds_url(txt:str):
    """
    >>> reminds_url('yandex.ru.com/somepath')
    True
    
    """
    ltext=txt.lower().split('/')[0]
    return ltext.startswith(('http','www','ftp')) or ltext.endswith(domain_suffixes)
```

Comment: I needed a stricter validator than what most answers implemented - correctly formed AND with a valid TDL. You answer gave me the neccessary second part, which I combined with a regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to conduct your own meaning of an "URL", and apply it everywhere in your code:

```py
#         DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE
#                 Version 2, December 2004
#
# Copyright (C) 2004 Sam Hocevar <sam@hocevar.net>
#
# Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim or modified
# copies of this license document, and changing it is allowed as long
# as the name is changed.
#
#         DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE
# TERMS AND CONDITIONS FOR COPYING, DISTRIBUTION AND MODIFICATION
#
# 0. You just DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO.
#
# Copyright © 2023 Anthony anthony@example.com
#
# This work is free. You can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
# terms of the Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License, Version 2,
# as published by Sam Hocevar. See the LICENSE file for more details.

import operator as op

from urllib.parse import (
    ParseResult,
    urlparse,
)

import attrs
import pytest

from phantom import Phantom
from phantom.fn import compose2


def is_url_address(value: str) -> bool:
    return any(urlparse(value))


class URL(str, Phantom, predicate=is_url_address):
    pass


# presume that an empty URL is a nonsense
def test_empty_url():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError, match="Could not parse .* from ''"):
        URL.parse("")


# is it enough now?
def test_url():
    assert URL.parse("http://")


scheme_and_netloc = op.attrgetter("scheme", "netloc")


def has_scheme_and_netloc(value: ParseResult) -> bool:
    return all(scheme_and_netloc(value))


# need a bit of FP magic  here
class ReachableURL(URL, predicate=compose2(has_scheme_and_netloc, urlparse)):
    pass


def test_empty_reachable_url():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError, match="Could not parse .* from ''"):
        ReachableURL.parse("")


# but "empty" for an URL is not just "empty string"
def test_reachable_url_probably_wrong_host():
    assert ReachableURL.parse("http://example")


def test_reachable_url():
    assert ReachableURL.parse("http://example.com")


def test_reachable_url_without_scheme():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError, match="Could not parse .* from 'example.com'"):
        ReachableURL.parse("example.com")


# constructor works too
def test_constructor():
    assert ReachableURL("http://example.com")


# but it *is* `str`
def test_url_is_str():
    assert isinstance(ReachableURL("http://example.com"), str)


# now we can write plain old classes utilizing our `URL` and `ReachableURL`

# I'm lazy...


@attrs.define
class Person:
    homepage: ReachableURL


def test_person():
    person = Person(homepage=ReachableURL("https://example.com/index.html"))

    assert person.homepage


def greet(person: Person) -> None:
    print(f"Hello! I will definitely visit you at {person.homepage}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    greet(Person(homepage=ReachableURL.parse("tg://resolve?username")))
```

It will not be surprising if an URL RFC turns out to be Turing-complete!

Answer (score 0):

This code uses socket, so you don't need to install it, because it is a built in library. It tries to connect to the input url.

```
import socket

def isValid(url):
    #connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually reachable
    try:
        socket.create_connection((url, 80))
        return True
    except socket.gaierror:
        return False
    except OSError:
        return False

A socket.gaierror occurs if the url is not valid, and an OSErrors occurs when you are not connected.
```

It returns True for both "https://www.google.com" and "google.com".

If it is a problem, you can simply use this code:

```
import socket

def isValid(url):
    if url.startswith("https://www.") or url.startswith("http://www."):
        try:
            socket.create_connection((url, 80))
            return True
        except socket.gaierror:
            return False
        except OSError:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_valid_url(url):
    try:
        result = urlparse(url)
        return all([result.scheme, result.netloc])
    except ValueError:
        return False

url = 'http://google.com'
if is_valid_url(url):
    print('Valid URL')
else:
    print('Malformed URL')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Function based on Dominic Tarro answer:

```
import re
def is_url(x):
    return bool(re.match(
        r"(https?|ftp)://" # protocol
        r"(\w+(\-\w+)*\.)?" # host (optional)
        r"((\w+(\-\w+)*)\.(\w+))" # domain
        r"(\.\w+)*" # top-level domain (optional, can have > 1)
        r"([\w\-\._\~/]*)*(?<!\.)" # path, params, anchors, etc. (optional)
    , x))
```