# simple web crawler

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i wrote below program in python for very simple web crawler, but when i run it it return me 
'NoneType' object is not callable' , could you please help me?

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
def union(p,q):
    for e in q:
        if e not in p:
            p.append(e)

def crawler(SeedUrl):
    tocrawl=[SeedUrl]
    crawled=[]
    while tocrawl:
        page=tocrawl.pop()
        pagesource=urllib2.urlopen(page)
        s=pagesource.read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s)
        links=soup('a')        
        if page not in crawled:
            union(tocrawl,links)
            crawled.append(page)

    return crawled
crawler('http://www.princeton.edu/main/')
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? That should at least narrow down what function call is being made on a `None` value.

Answer (score 6):

**[UPDATE] Here is the complete project code**

https://bitbucket.org/deshan/simple-web-crawler

**[ANWSER]**

soup('a') returns the complete html tag.

```
<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/store">Buy Music Now</a>
```

so the **urlopen** gives the error 
 **'NoneType' object is not callable'**. you need extract the only the url/href.

```
links=soup.findAll('a',href=True)
for l in links:
    print(l['href'])
```

You need to validate the url too.refer to following anwsers

- [How do you validate a URL with a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python)
- [Python - How to validate a url in python ? (Malformed or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not)

Again i would like to suggest you to use python sets instead Arrays.you can easily add,ommit duplicate urls.

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

**Try the following code:**

```
import re
import httplib
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse
import BeautifulSoup

regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
        r'localhost|' #localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
        r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)

def isValidUrl(url):
    if regex.match(url) is not None:
        return True;
    return False

def crawler(SeedUrl):
    tocrawl=[SeedUrl]
    crawled=[]
    while tocrawl:
        page=tocrawl.pop()
        print 'Crawled:'+page
        pagesource=urllib2.urlopen(page)
        s=pagesource.read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s)
        links=soup.findAll('a',href=True)        
        if page not in crawled:
            for l in links:
                if isValidUrl(l['href']):
                    tocrawl.append(l['href'])
            crawled.append(page)   
    return crawled
crawler('http://www.princeton.edu/main/')
```