# Using beautiful soup in python 2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to build a basic web crawler using Beautiful soup in python 2.7. 
Here is my code:

```
import re
import httplib
import urllib2
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|https)s?://' # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
        r'localhost|' #localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
        r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)

def isValidUrl(url):
    if regex.match(url) is not None:
        return True;
    return False

def crawler(SeedUrl):
    tocrawl=[SeedUrl]
    crawled=[]
    while tocrawl:
        page=tocrawl.pop()
        print 'Crawled:'+page
        pagesource=urllib2.urlopen(page)
        s=pagesource.read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s)
        links=soup.findAll('a',href=True)        
        if page not in crawled:
            for l in links:
                if isValidUrl(l['href']):
                    tocrawl.append(l['href'])
            crawled.append(page)   
    return crawled

crawler('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SfWxVs65JK_v8we9zrj4AQ&gws_rd=ssl')
```

I am getting the error:

Crawled:https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SfWxVs65JK_v8we9zrj4AQ&gws_rd=ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_crawler_python_2.py", line 38, in 
    crawler('https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SfWxVs65JK_v8we9zrj4AQ&gws_rd=ssl')
  File "web_crawler_python_2.py", line 29, in crawler
    soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s)
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'

I tried a lot but can't seem to debug it. Can anyone point me to the problem. (As a side note, I know that many websites do not allow crawling, but I'm just doing it to learn).

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Source I have used for the code: [simple web crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658863/simple-web-crawler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class hasn't attribute BeautifulSoup. I don't know why you used it. Example from [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

You need replace:

```
BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup
```

to

```
BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Can you please tell me what was the problem ?

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi: the usage `soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s)` is good for version 3; for version 4, the usage is: `soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)`