# How to check whether the given url is valid or not in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I need to check whether the given url is valid or not in django. I have used URLValidator for checking the url in django. But it's not working. I have explained the code below.

```
 from django.core.validators import URLValidator
 from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
 a = "www.google.com"
 url = URLValidator()
 try:
    url(a)
    print "correct"
 except:
    print "wrong"
```

When i tried to run the above concept it's showing the output **"wrong"**. And then when i passed the value of **a="http://www.google.com"** means that the output is **"correct"**. After that when i passed the value of **a="http://www.googlecom"** means that the output is **"correct"** .am more confused with it. Please anyone help me to do this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this issue was discussed here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not

Answer (score 2):

`"www.google.com"` is not valid [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) because there is no protocol (`http` or `https` for example). It is malformed.

`"http://www.googlecom"` is treated as a valid url by Django because it has the right format (`protocol://something.something`). Although this url does not work, it is not malformed.

...Django does not try to check if `googlecom` is a valid [Top-Level Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) because there are lots of those and the set is changing often. It only checks that the URL is not malformed.