# How to configure Flask to consider URL as one argument passed through CURL command

Tags: python, http, url, curl, flask

```
import Flask
app.route('/urlinfo/1/<URL>', methods=['GET'])
def search(URL):
  print URL
```

I am making curl command to to test it

```
curl  http://127.0.0.1:5000/urlinfo/1/http://www.dsdsd.com
```

Since URL include '//' Flask consider it as a second argument and throw an error.

1.How to pass whole URL as an one argument in

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/urlinfo/1/http://www.dsdsd.com/path command?
```

2.How to check that  Enter URL is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your decorator to this:

```
@app.route('/urlinfo/1/<path:URL>', methods=['GET'])
```

By adding `path` to the URL arguments, slashes should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks yeah It resolved the issue.how can i verify that URL is valid.I mean basic check?

Comment: @guri take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32171869/7090605

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.I stumble upon it earlier but I am trying to avoid installing extra package and trying to achieve with inbuilt libraries

Comment: @guri you could always borrow the code for the method from that package. It uses `re`, which is a builtin library. https://github.com/kvesteri/validators/blob/master/validators/domain.py

Comment: I am using the way you said
**@app.route('/urlinfo/1/<path:URL>', methods=['GET'])** and it is now treating URL as a single argument but when I am passing URL like  **http://127.0.0.1:5000/urlinfo/1/'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RB89BOxaYY'** it is neglecting URL after '?'.Is there any way it does not neglect URL after '?'

Comment: @guri concatenate `str(request.query_string)` to the URL string before printing it. Right now, Flask things that `?v=6RB89BOxaYY%27` is a URL query, and not part of the URL, so you have to add it back with `request.query_string`.

Comment: [Percent encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `?` (`%3F`) may do the trick.