# Python Regex for URLs

Tags: python

need help with Python regex for URLs

```
    re.findall(r"((^hxxp|http|https)+:+//+([a-zA-Z]{1,32})+((.){1,4})+(([a-z]|.){1,10}))", datastream)
```

This is matching full URLs as designed but also chunks of the string to be matched resulting in Python crapping out.

I would prefer to use findall using .match would require some sizeable changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7160778/2958070

Comment: can you share `datastream` ?

Comment: thanks for redirecting. but i have scoured SO and my regex while flawed is the most logical regex so far that I have found so. Datastream is 'hxxp://www.somedomain[.]de/fjhiadsg'