# Using Adf.ly with Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So I am using MurkAPI **and had gotten help with this** but I cannot seem to get it so when someone does $adfly and a url which is a adfly shortend link, the bot returns the link through the API and into the bot. This is the current code I have.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def adfly(self, ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            await self.client.say(await fetch_adfly(session))
async def fetch_adfly(session):
    async with session.get(adfly_url) as response:
        return await response.text()
```

I have the MURKKEY working, however, I cannot get the URL part working.

```
adfly_url = 'https://murkapi.com/adfly.php?key={}&url={}'.format(MURKKEY)
```

Comment: What part of the URL isn't working? Also, your command doesn't have an argument for the url, did you mean to add one?

Comment: So basically the users do like $adfly (adfly link) and the bot will return the link behind the adfly link. I just can't figure that part out as I am not really good with Python. And yes, I mean to add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fetch_adfly` is meant to handle transforming your `url` into an adfly url, you want the session in that function. Instead of passing a session, we want to pass the `url` that we want transformed. That might give us something like:

```
async def fetch_adfly(url):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    adfly_url = 'https://murkapi.com/adfly.php?key={}&url={}'.format(MURKKEY, url)
    async with session.get(adfly_url) as response:
        return await response.text()
```

Then, you want to add a `url` parameter to your command and pass it to your function:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def adfly(self, ctx, url):
  await self.client.say(await fetch_adfly(url))
```

FWIW, I would suggest [validating URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not).

Comment: It's supposed to transform an adfly link into the link behind it which is done via the API

Comment: Can you please clarify how the intended behavior differs from this solution?

Comment: When using your solution, I do $adfly (Adfly link I want to get the actual link from behidn it) It says URL cannot be found. I want it so when someone does $adfly (adfly url) they get the real URL behind the adfly link

Comment: Do a `print(adfly_url)` and see what the full url it's trying to call is. However it sounds like the 'not found' issue may be on murkapi's end.

Comment: It is their end, I have called the API through my browser and got the same results. I have contact MurkAPI staff about this issue.