# how can I use this regular expression to validate a valid url in python

Tags: python

I have this regular expression to validate that a string is a valid url:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

I do not know how to use it.

```
url="www.google.com"
print(re.compile(r'/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/',url))
```

Can someone give me a hand please?
thank you

Comment: Do to use random regular expressions to validate URLs. Almost all of them are flawed. Use  [specialized tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not).

Comment: Also see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/835527/4492932).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you don't need the first and last slash python automatically uses them, secondly you need to make your expression a re object

```
import re
expr = re.compile(r'((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(:[0-9]+)?|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)')
```

after that you can use the function match to see if the expression returns a valid instance

```
url="www.google.com"

if expr.match(url):
    print("It is valid")
```