# How to check if a URL exists or not?

Tags: python, http

I wrote this python code to open sockets but I can't figure out how to check if a URL exists or not

```
inp = input('Enter a URL: ')
ipt = inp.split('/')
inu = ipt[2]

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((inu, 80))
cmd = 'GET x HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
mmd = cmd.replace('x',inp)
bmd = mmd.encode()
mysock.send(bmd)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate a url in Python? (Malformed or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not)

Comment: Define "validate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One would be to use the validator module. It would look something like this:

```python
import validators

valid=validators.url('https://codespeedy.com/')
if valid==True:
    print("Url is valid")
else:
    print("Invalid url")
```

Another way would be to use the requests module, like this:

```python
import requests

try:
    response = requests.get("http://www.google.com/")
    print("URL is valid and exists on the internet")
except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
    print("URL does not exist on Internet")
```