# How to check if a dataframe is in the URL format or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame like:

```
df['website']
```

I want a condition that df['website'] should contain the only names of websites in the URL form. If the data frame has other sentences rather than URL it should display a warning message.

Comment: Please include some sample [`reproducible`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/4985099) input along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use validators package.
If you want to know more about it, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not).

After getting a function which returns whether url is valid or not, you can use df.apply() and apply that function to all URLs in the dataframe. You can return ture/false for whether it's valid or not. Moreover, in the function, you can print a warning if you find it's invalid.

```
import validators

def isUrlValid(url):
    return True if validators.url(url) else False
df['isURLValid'] = df['website'].apply(isUrlValid)
```

Output:

```
website     isURLValid
0   https://stackoverflow.com/  True
1   no  False
```

Lastly, if you don't want to add the results as  a column in a dataframe, you can loop through all values in `df['website'].tolist()` and call the function for each value and print warning in the function

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about the alert.

but to check as for the "url formatting" you could write a function to check for usual url elements like: "http" or ".com". Or even if the data has "." in it.

it really depends on your data...