# Validating JUST the path of a URL in Python

Tags: python

What's the best way to validate that a string is a valid URL **path** in Python?

I want to avoid maintaining a complex regex if possible.

I have this regex so far but I am looking for alternatives because it does not cover all cases for **just the path** segment:

```py
def check_valid_path(v):
    pattern = r"^\/[-a-z\d_\/]*$"
    if not compile(pattern).match(v):
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid path: {v}. Must match {pattern}")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse?

Comment: @jonrsharpe From the doc: `Warning urlparse() does not perform validation. See URL parsing security for details.`

Comment: Not sure there is a satisfying answer, but the question is essentially the same one that was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not

Comment: form [pydantic - url validtion regex](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/ca2fbdc5463a367b7b61f7ca437cfeae7c6ba524/pydantic/v1/networks.py#L342), check the regex for the url of your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic is a popular data validation package and has got may ready-made options for many common scenarios. It has [several alternatives for URLs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/urls/), here's an example with `HttpUrl`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl, ValidationError

class UrlValidator(BaseModel):
    url: HttpUrl

def validate(url: str):
    try:
        UrlValidator(url=url)
    except ValidationError:
        print("Not a valid url")
    else:
        print("Valid url")
```

```
>>> validate("asd")
Not a valid url
>>> validate("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76950928/validating-a-path-in-python")
Valid url
```

Comment: This only works for full URLs, I am validating just the path part

Comment: Mine was just an example, you need to have a look at your specific field type. Have a look at `FileUrl` or `FilePath` or simply use `Path` from `pathlib`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `urllib.parse.urlparse` function to parse the URL.
Then, you can check if the `scheme` and `netloc` components are empty and the `path` component is not empty. This generally indicates a valid URL path.

Comment: While this is useful, it does not check if the path is valid: From the doc: `Warning urlparse() does not perform validation. See URL parsing security for details.`