# django URLValidator produced bogus errors

Tags: python, django, url-validation

I'm using the Django `URLValidator` in the following way in a form:

```
def clean_url(self):
    validate = URLValidator(verify_exists=True)
    url = self.cleaned_data.get('url')

    try:
        logger.info(url)
        validate(url)
    except ValidationError, e:
        logger.info(e)
        raise forms.ValidationError("That website does not exist. Please try again.")

    return self.cleaned_data.get('url')
```

It seems to work with some url's but for some valid ones, it fails. I was able to check with http://www.amazon.com/ it's failing (which is obviously incorrect). It passes with http://www.cisco.com/. Is there any reason for the bogus errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [the source for `URLValidator`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/validators.py#L94); if you specify `check_exists`, it makes a `HEAD` request to the URL to check if it's valid:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
req.get_method = lambda: 'HEAD'
...
opener.open(req, timeout=10)
```

Try making the `HEAD` request to Amazon yourself, and you'll see the problem:

```
carl@chaffinch:~$ HEAD http://www.amazon.com
405 MethodNotAllowed
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 18:50:56 GMT
Server: Server
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Allow: POST, GET
...
```

I can't see a way of solving this other than monkey-patching or otherwise extending `URLValidator` to use a `GET` or `POST` request; before doing so, you should think carefully about whether to use `check_exists` at all (without which this problem should go away). As `core/validators.py` itself says,

> "The `URLField` `verify_exists` argument has intractable security and performance issues. Accordingly, it has been deprecated."

You'll find that the in-development version of Django has indeed disposed of this feature completely.